# The transaction currency specified must be the same as previously specified

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

Hello I try to create a payment with EURO in PayPal but getting an error. But it works fine when I use payment with USD.

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014-09-26T10:03:06Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 4d802c104e0ae
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 64
[BUILD] => 13055236
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10444
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The transaction currency specified must be the same as previously specified.
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

Comment: There could be an error in how you specify the currency. Show your code.

Comment: Plese review on this http://teste.ebroselow.com/Paypal.php

Comment: I was referring to your code, not a code example. This example uses AUD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your code with this, paypal Deprecated some field like

**PAYMENTACTION**  to   **PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTACTION**

**AMT** TO  **PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT**

**CUSTOM** to   **PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM**

```
$nvpstr = "&TOKEN=" . $token;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale";
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYERID=" . $payerID;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=" . $userId;  
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=".$currency;
```

you make these changes in "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" API call it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two parameters related to the currency in the "SetExpressCheckout" API call like below :

**$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;**

**$nvpstr.='&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.$currencyCodeType;**

But in the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" API call you are passing only one :

**$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=".$currency;**

You should pass only one parameter related to currency in both the API call :
**$nvpstr.='&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.$currencyCodeType;**

Once you make these changes in your "SetExpressCheckout" API call it should be fine

Comment: But in your url above "http://teste.ebroselow.com/Paypal.php" , still you are passing both parameters..

Comment: its a demo file i have changed from my original code